# Google Camera says "Can't take photo: Not enough storage left on this device."

Tags: lineageos, 9.0-pie, google-photos

On a recently flashed LineageOS 16 Device, I'm getting with Google Photo

> Can't take photo: Not enough storage left on this device.

The File Browser shows 234 GB Free.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if I did anything before hand, but force-quitting the application and restarting it made it work.